# Inline functions in pl/sql?

Tags: function, plsql, inline, oracle9i

I have 5 lines of code as function which is being called 100000 times is there a way to make the function inline so that I don't experienced a call overhead in PL/SQL. Oracle 9i is the version I am using.

Update:
The In lining of code does not have much improvement but I gained 2 seconds though. Now I am looking for efficient version of float data type in pl/sql. BINARY FLOAT did not work, NUMBER(10,5) is the one already being employed.

Comment: `PRAGMA INLINE` was only introduced in Oracle 11g, unfortunately. http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/inline_pragma.htm#CJAEHDEB

Comment: Have you determined that there is significant detrimental overhead in calling this function?

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp that is why I specified oracle 9i, do you have any idea whether it would do any good if I manually inline, any idea on how much the function call overhead would be with b/w 100000 - 1000000?.

Comment: @Charles I suspect since the function is called so many times and the performance penalty is in that function, anyway I will dig and let you know soon, as the week end already started here :).

Comment: @yesraaj, that is why I made it a comment instead of an "answer" :)

Comment: It really depends on what those 5 lines of code are doing. Perhaps if you post the code we might have an idea. Also, look at the parameters - perhaps some of the overhead has to do with converting data types, or copying large chunks of data.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp I don't have access to the code right now, but all it essentially does is get a random number, using oracle random function, multiply with a constant inside a branching statement and return the value. And it has a exception block to catch if there is any exception. Better I will get ride of the function itself and the exception block as well and I will keep you posted.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp seems there is very minimal improvement 2 seconds gain with in lining of code manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've determined that the function call overhead is not contributing much to the performance issue, so inlining would not be helpful here anyway.

**I assume you're not running any SQL or calling any SQL functions in your PL/SQL? If so I'd look there next.**

Your next option is native compilation - see [Compiling PL/SQL Code for Native Execution](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/12_tune.htm#48417) for details. You might get some improvement since you're only doing maths.

Otherwise, you may need to look beyond PL/SQL. You can call code written in many other languages from PL/SQL, including C, C++ and Java. Refer to [Calling External Procedures](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg11rtn.htm) for more info.

Comment: actually I am calling sin and cos function that takes up to 7 seconds, how can i minimize that?

Comment: how many times are you calling the function? how many sin/cos calls is it making? are the arguments very unique or are there many repeating arguments (i.e. could you cache the results for commonly-occurring values?)

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp I can't cache sin/cos because they vary all the time but, I can eliminate select statement inside the loop, I am looking for a map(key, value) kind of data structure in pl/sql.

Comment: @yesraaj: did you read my answer? "I assume you're not running any SQL or calling any SQL functions in your PL/SQL?" If you're running any SQL, it doesn't matter how often you call sin/cos, I'd be 99.9% sure that the SQL queries are the problem. sigh :(

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp yes I read your answer, as you said major performance lag will be due to SQL, I am trying to eliminate the select query, but with out sin/cos functions I could save 6 seconds that is 25% of time needed for the whole procedure to run.

Comment: Is the SQL the other 75% of the time? If so I'd focus on that first.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp because I could do the SQL removal myself and needed help on math function call, I am asking only about that here. I am caching the values of select statement during first call and populating the values in a map for rest of the run that would be fine for removing the SQL statement right or do you want to remove the SQL out of the loop? About cos function do you have any idea to get a approximated version of cosine that performs better than the usually cos fn?

Comment: Have you measured the time it takes to actually run the SQL statement, not including the times when you use the cache? RE the cos function, sorry I don't know.

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp yes I got 2 sec gain after the caching